# Doing ajax with Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been loading content with ajax and all works fine. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

//Load a-z.php
//Timestamp resolves IE caching issue
var tsTimeStamp= new Date().getTime();
$.post('../../includes/categories/a-z.php',
      {action: "post", time: tsTimeStamp},
      function(data){
        $('#moviescontainer').html(data).slideDown('slow');
      });
return true;                           

});
```

My data inside a-z.php requires Javascript for it's content and when I load a-z.php onto my page the javascript doesn't work.

I am quessing that I need to link the relevant files to a-z.php and then load it via ajax.

Doesn't this kind of defeat the object of ajax?? That means that I will be loading the js files on the main page and then loading them again when I ajax a-z.php

I hope I made some sense.

EDIT: The A-Z.php page references external javascript files that I have already included on my main page (example: the jquery library, That will mean i am loading it twice.

When I mean requires javascript for its content I have a few modal boxes etc that open when content is clicked. These use the Jquery library)

Comment: In general, that should work.  Can you show us the Javascript that doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by "requires Javascript for it's content"?  Is there already Javascript on your page that is supposed to act on content provided by a-z.php?  Does a-z.php have inline Javascript?  Does a-z.php reference an external javascript file?

Comment: Please see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that you need to add the `defer` attribute to the script tag, which defers executing the script until the content is loaded.

[see here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)

you should not have to load the scripts a second time.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: The A-Z.php page references
>   external javascript files that I have
>   already included on my main page
>   (example: the jquery library, That
>   will mean i am loading it twice.

Simply omit them from the `a-z.php` page then. If they're already included on the main page, they'll be available to the `a-z.php` script when it's loaded in via ajax. However, I suspect any `onload` or `$(document).ready()` calls won't work quite right. I'd try to remove as much JS as possible out of the `a-z.php` page.

Comment: I think the problem is that the javascript is within $(document).ready(). How would I get around this??

Comment: Don't use it then. Replace `$(document).ready()` with your own function, and then call it manually from inside your `$.post` callback func (or simply move the code into the callback).

Comment: @user272899 - `$(document).ready()` will work fine...if the document is already ready, it will execute immediately, it's not like an event that's already fired.

Comment: @Nick: Oh... that's cool. Because that's what I was worried about... his problem must be somewhere else then?